# Erasable yet bold crayon for Empire Builder Games (e.g. Eurorails)?

Tags: game-accessories, crayon-rail-games

We have kids, so we have lots of types of crayons in the house.  Everything from airline freebie to crayola.  None of them are very satisfactory for Eurorails (and related games).  Either they are too light to see or they won't erase easily.  The original factory crayons are long since gone/lost.

What crayon do people recommend for Eurorails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to take the map to a map or printing shop, laminate it properly, and use overhead pens. Or to use clear laminate purchased in rolls at a home-decorating or home improvement shop.

Now, I used china markers on a couple crayon maps in the past, and even they don't erase completely cleanly from all "factory laminated" boards.

Another good option is a sheet of plexiglass or sheet vinyl and overhead pens over the map. Plexiglass sheets are available in many home repair shops. Rolled clear vinyl is available in many fabric stores (for making covers for furniture and for covering lace tablecloths). These have the advantage of being able to be washed in the sink.

Comment: Overhead pens... that would work.  I'd need to wet remove them.

Comment: On factory laminate, you use a damp sponge, in several passes. If you use a hot-application laminate, you leave the 1-2mm edge on the map, and can just rinse it in the shower. For an adhesive laminate, you need to either over-shoot the edges 2-3mm, or tape the edges, in order to assure water-resistance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will get a definitive answer, but probably just lots of suggestions. There has been.discussion about this [question before on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8584972#8584972). You are going to get a range of answers:

- Crayola Washable Crayons.
- China Markers.
- Dry Erase Markers
- Wet Erase Markers.
- Standard Crayola Crayons

Answer (score 2):

I found Crayola brand washable crayons to work the best. For the lack of boldness I subbed brown for yellow, purple for orange. I bought both Empire Builder and Empire Express straight from Mayfair but got different crayons with each. Express came with no-name crayons that leave a slight stain on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend China markers ([Like these)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039Y2JXU).  Just be sure to test them first.  I had a yellow one once that wouldn't entirely erase.

Answer (score -1):

From [BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1049403/found-replacement-markers-that-work), one user reports that Crayola Washable Markers work well.